# Recurring SQLite Error - Unable to open database file

Tags: linux, database, r, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I am cleaning and reshaping for analysis. It is approximately 120GB in size.

We bought a much better machine, more cores, 20x the RAM, etc. It also has a set of four 1TB drives (I have the `root` on one physical drive, and I have `/home` on a RAID0 array of the other three physical drives).

I was working on a machine with much fewer resources to start and my script ran perfectly (albeit slowly). I never had these errors and corruptions. But when I ran the exact same script on the new machine I starting getting this error. I am unable to open the database. I have backups, but this is happening so frequently that I haven't made any progress on the analysis since moving to the new machine.

```
Error in sqliteNewConnection(drv, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect to dbname:
unable to open database file
)
Calls: insertLinks ... .valueClassTest -> is -> is -> sqliteNewConnection -> .Call
In addition: Warning message:
In mclapply(idx, function(idx1) { :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
Execution halted
```

Every insert I perform (1,000 - 10,000 records at a time) is encapsulated in a transcation. Here is the code that causes this specific error above.

```
insertLinks <- function(b) {

  con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbpro)
  sql <- 'insert into link (emailid, md5, field, email, domain, company) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
  dbBeginTransaction(con)
  dbGetPreparedQuery(con, sql, bind.data = b)
  dbCommit(con)
  dbDisconnect(con)

}
```

Error when I run the .log stdout and try to open the database from inside SQLite prompt

```
(14) cannot open file at line 29016 of [27392118af]
(14) os_unix.c:29016: (2) open((unreachable)/databaseFile.db)
```

Comment: So the name of the directory is `(unreachable)`?

Comment: That is from the text of the error. The directory should be /home/jesse/workingfolder/database.db

Comment: And that is the exact path you gave to `.open`?

Comment: The R script uses the full file path for the database. Note that the script works for thousands of passes  before this error occurs. But for the .open, no, I just specified the filename.